# Laravel 4 Cron Job Artisan Namespace

Tags: laravel-4, cron

When I run my laravel command via the terminal it works. But when I Run the command via CRON it fails with the following message.

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                              
  There are no commands defined in the "check" namespace.
```

I have added:

```
Artisan::add(new CheckRecentlyApprovedAccounts);
```

to the artisan.php file

When I run:

```
php artisan list
```

In the terminal output I can see my command listed.

The Cron is running the following command:

```
php -d register_argc_argv=On /home/blahblah/artisan check:accounts
```

What should I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: In your command class, what do you have for the name?  
protected $name = ???;

Comment: protected $name = 'check:accounts';

Comment: my cron command is now php /home/blahblah/artisan check:accounts

Comment: There is something different between me running the same command in my terminal and the cron job being able to run it ?

Comment: Everything you have provided looks good.  It could be a problem with your working directory when the cron script runs.  Try using a script that makes sure your currenty directory is where your artisan command is located.

Comment: Fixed it! I needed /usr/local/bin/php